# Is it possible to have a dynamic sort range?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, range

I was wondering if I can create a macro that sorts my worksheet with a range that is constantly changing? Instead of the last row constantly changing, the top row count will be changing. 
Is it possible to have my .setrange be a variable which gets updated with the new range based on arguments?
For example the current code I have sets my range starting at A5 but if rows 6 - 10 have an interior color of green I want it to leave those at the top and only sort starting from A11.

```
activesheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
activesheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("M6"), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With activesheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A5:O150") ' I want this range to change constantly without me manually changing, for example it would be from ("A10:0150") now
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Sure. What's the logic in question? Whether the cells are green?

Comment: Will there be any other **non** Green cells in the range to be excluded from the sort other than `A5`?

Comment: @BigBen, the logic is for Column E if the cell is white (Color index = -4142) then that should be part of the range to sort. All other rows should be excluded if they are not white. There will be possibly be cells that can be red, green, yellow and so on.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ^

Comment: Will the rows to be excluded all be **contiguous**, starting with the first row of data?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes the rows will be sharing the same boarder. There will never be an instance where non excluded data will be between excluded data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This UDF will return a range object representing your sort range as defined by the first row of data in the fifth column containing a "white" interior (not including the first row, unless that is the ONLY row with a white interior):

```
Option Explicit
Private Function SortRange(baseRange As Range) As Range
    Dim firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range, C As Range

With baseRange
    Set lastCell = .Worksheet.Cells(.Row + .Rows.Count - 1, .Column + .Columns.Count - 1)
End With

With Application.FindFormat
    .Clear
    .Interior.Color = vbWhite
End With

'find the first cell in fifth column that is white
'As implemented, this should be column E, but if you move the range, it will adjust to the 5th column
'after the first row in baseRange
With baseRange
    Set firstCell = .Columns(5).Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 5), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, searchformat:=True)

    If Not firstCell Is Nothing Then
        With .Worksheet
            Set SortRange = .Range(.Cells(firstCell.Row, 1), lastCell)
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "no cells to sort"
        Exit Function
    End If
End With

End Function
```

You could then use it like:

```
.SetRange SortRange(activesheet.range("A3:O150"))
```

but I would suggest replacing `activesheet` with the actual worksheet.

Comment: Thank you Ron for your reply and code. Unfortunately, it didn't work. It is still sorting the top rows that aren't white. I also tried changing the call out from 'SortRange(activesheet.range("A3:O150"))' to 'SortRange(activesheet.range("A5:O150"))' Which ended up not sorting at all. I've also tried  changing the ranges in the call out firstcell from 'after:=.Cells(1, 5)' to different numbers, which also resulted in nothing sorting.

Comment: @jawvis I didn't really look closely at your Sort code. Only at your question about changing `SetRange` dynamically. You probably need to change the `Key` also to reflect the range you wish to sort.  Instead of a single cell, it should reflect the entire column of that data to be sorted (excluding a header row).  You could use a column offset from the range object returned by SortRange function.

Comment: @jawvis you may also want to set the `header` argument to `xlNo`.

Comment: ahh Okay, that makes sense. Thank you for your help! I got it to work. I kept the `Key` range as is since my columns have various dates and column M is the final date. I did change the `header` to xlNo and the `.range("A5:O150")`.